# Unable to retrieve value from Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, catalog, phtml, catalogsearch

I am using Magento 2.3.5-p2

I am adding a Google Tag Manager integration code at the Catalog Search, thus this requires me to modify the `catalogsearch_result_index.xml` and add a new .phtml file which I called it `gtm_body.phtml` this file will contain the GTM code integration

here is the code that I have updated at the

`app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/layout01/Magento_CatalogSearch/layout/catalogsearch_result_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="div.sidebar.main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar-main-content"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="categorymenu" destination="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-"/>
        <move element="div.sidebar.main" destination="columns" before="-"/>
        <move element="main" destination="columns" after="div.sidebar.main"/>
    </body>

    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Magento_CatalogSearch::html/gtm_body.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>

</page>
```

here is the content for

`app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/layout01/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml`

```
<?php

$result = 'no results found';

var_dump($block->getResultCount());die;

if($block->getResultCount()){
    $result = 'results found';
}

?>

<script>

dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'trackEvent',
    'eventDetails.category': 'site search',
    'eventDetails.action': '<?php echo $result; ?>',
    'eventDetails.label': '<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\CatalogSearch\Helper\Data')->getEscapedQueryText(); ?>'
});

</script>
```

the `$block->getResultCount()` are supposedly to carry the result for amount of product for the search result but error such as below appear

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getLoadedProductCollection() on bool 
in /var/www/ecmc/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Block/Result.php:182 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/ecmc/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Block/Result.php(206): 
Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result->_getProductCollection() 
#1 /var/www/ecmc/app/design/frontend/MageBig/martfury/layout01/Magento_CatalogSearch/templates/html/gtm_body.phtml(5): Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result->getResultCount() 
#2 /var/www/ecmc/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/ecmc...') 
#3 /var/www/ecmc/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result), '/var/www/ecmc...', Array) 
#4 /var/www/ecmc/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/ecmc...') 
#5 /var/www/ecmc/vendor/magento/framework/Vi in /var/www/ecmc/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Block/Result.php on line 182
```

I have debug this code by going through the block file at
`vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Block/Result.php`

upon `var_dump($block->getListBlock());` I noticed that this value return `bool(false)`

I am not able to understand what is causing this value to be false, the false value is what causing the `function _getProductCollection()` unable to get the value for the `getLoadedProductCollection` function

do help and explain on why this problem occur and how to solve this problem

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot add the search results block to the layout once again as it has already been initiated. You should create a separate block for your purposes and call the existing results block from it. Here are the steps:

1. **Create a new block** app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/GtmSearchResult.php with the following content:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

   use Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result;
   use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

   class GtmSearchResult extends Template
   {
       /**
        * @return Result
        */
       public function getResultsBlock()
       {
           return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('search.result');
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Update your layout file** to use this block:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="div.sidebar.main">
               <container name="div.sidebar.main.content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar-main-content"/>
           </referenceContainer>
           <move element="categorymenu" destination="catalogsearch.leftnav" before="-"/>
           <move element="div.sidebar.main" destination="columns" before="-"/>
           <move element="main" destination="columns" after="div.sidebar.main"/>

           <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
               <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\GtmSearchResult" name="gtm.body" before="-" template="Vendor_Module::gtm_body.phtml" />
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. **Update your template file**:

   ```
   <?php

   $result = 'no results found';

   var_dump($block->getResultsBlock()->getResultCount());
   die;
   ```

Comment: Thank You, good explanation, followed your guidelines, and now its working already

Comment: One thing I noticed is that after using this new custom block created, it cause the search result to show up different than the current one, why do this happen ya